# Minimal working example of __instancecheck__

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass

I am trying to write a stupid `__instancecheck__` for class `Class` so the following will print `False`:

```
c = Class()
print(isinstance(c, Class)) # False
```

I tried to put `__instancecheck__` in Class, BaseClass and MetaClass, but nothing works. Here is the code:

```
class MetaClass(type):
    def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
        return False


class BaseClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
        return False


class Class(BaseClass, metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
        return False

c = Class()
print(isinstance(c, Class))  # True
```

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) says the method should be in metaclass, I did it, and it's not working and I can't inderstand why. Please tell me where I am wrong.